# Random shuffle of <table> columns

Tags: jquery

I have a tricky situation to solve. I am trying to shuffle columns of a table and its data randomly using jquery or any plugin available.

I am able to shift the column to specific position but what I want achieve is to shuffle column and its data randomly to any position.

example:

Actual:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Data One</td>
    <td>Data Two</td>
    <td>Data Three</td>
    <td>Data Four</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Expected: (Not in exact format as I want columns to be shuffled randomly to any position)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Data Two</td>
    <td>Data Five</td>
    <td>Data One</td>
    <td>Data Three</td>
    <td>Data Four</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have been able to shift individual column to a particular position using detach() method and insertBefore() at required position

Comment: Show us your code (edit the question)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually extremely trivial using external libraries. Underscore JS has a shuffle method which can be used to great effect.

Shuffle: http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/NfvBa/

```
var rows = $('tr');
$.each(rows, function(index, value) {
    var cells = $('td', value);
    var shuffledCells = _.shuffle(cells);
    $(this).html(shuffledCells);
});
```

That's all it takes.

**EDIT:** Given your new requirement of wanting the data to move together, I have thrown together this example: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/NfvBa/3/

In this example, I store the data we're interested in as a Name Value pair array. That way we can shuffle the array once, then pluck the properties we're interested in. After we pluck the values I then inject them into the table rows. I gave the table rows classes, but, it could be done with straight CSS selectors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, Got really excited with the answer. but the problem with this shuffle is header and its data are shuffled independently. I want to keep header and data in sync as well. if one moves to certain position, the data below it should also move to the corresponding position

Comment: Without adding some sort of relation to the data this is going to be quite difficult. The data at the moment is completely unrelated. If it was me I'd create an array of name value pairs and shuffle that array then inject it into the table.